# How to manipulate routes if the page is visited first?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

So I have this simple method in a modal:

```
showModal(value) {
  if (value === true) {
    if (this.isOpen === true) {
      //do something here
    }
    this.showModal = true;
  } else {
    this.showModal = false;
    router.go(-1);
    // if this is the first page they visited then 
    // router.push('/dashboard');
  }
},
```

this method is triggered by a click from a "go back" button. 
However, `router.go(-1)` performs well if there are other pages clicked before this. But what if the page was the first thing they went to? Is there a way that I can check if that is the first page they went to? and redirect them to `/dashboard` if it is?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [`window.history.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/length) property. If it is 1, you are on the first page. Also,

```
const routes = [
 {
   path: '/',
   redirect: 'dashboard'
 }, 
 ...
]
```

is the best way to configure initial redirect with [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript).